# Getting data from sqlite on android is really slow

Tags: android, sql, performance, sqlite

I have this code:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
System.out.println("Start - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
for (int i = 1; i < db.getChampsCount() + 1; i++) {
    String name = db.getChampInfo(i, "name");
    String title = db.getChampInfo(i, "title");
    String thumb = db.getChampInfo(i, "thumb");
    System.out.println("End - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    [...]
}
```

and this

```
String getChampInfo(int id, String col) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + col + " FROM champions WHERE id = " + id, new String[] {});
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    db.close();
    return cursor.getString(0);
}
```

Which is a part of DatabaseHelper class

And it works ok, but the problem is it takes way too long to execute (2089ms on my android phone). Those strings are a part of the UI so I don't think I can put that in another thread. What can i do to make this code run faster?

Edit: there are exactly 110 rows

Comment: you could probably get around 3x the speed if you use a single SQL statement

Comment: how many rows you have in champions table. I'm assuming id is the primary key? Can't think why it's slow, primary key should be indexed.. hmm..

Comment: +1 for Alex Juan Gittemeier. Combine your SQL. Not need to query each column separately.

Comment: post your table structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of individual statement, should you not use Single sql statement ?

Just create one ArrayList which will store all the required value in the Activity class.

e.g: `ArrayList<String> myData;`

Now in database helper class make one function like below:

```
 // TO get All Data of datanase which you want
public ArrayList<String> getAllData() {          
    ArrayList<String> subTitleList = null;         
    Cursor cursor = null;          
    try {              
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM champions";              
        cursor =  db.rawQuery(queryString, null);              
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {                 
            subTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();                 
            do {                     
                String nextUser = new String(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));                     
                String nextUser = new String(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));                     
                String nextUser = new String(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("thumb")));                     

                subTitleList.add(nextUser);                 
            } 
            while (cursor.moveToNext());   
            System.out.println("it comes in SubTitleList");
        }         
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {             
        e.printStackTrace();             
        subTitleList = null;         
    } 
    finally {             
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {                 
            cursor.deactivate();                 
            cursor.close();                 
            cursor = null;             
        }             
        if(db != null){                 
            db.close();             
        }         
    }
    //System.out.println("SubTitleList is: "+subTitleList);
    return subTitleList;   
}
```

And now in your activity class you can call this function and get all the required data from the myData ArrayList.

```
myData = db.getAllData(); // i think there is no need of any ID if you are fetching all the data.
```

Hope you got my point.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Just make little correction is. If you want to get the data of whole Table and there are more field then you can store it in the Any Object Class which have geter, seter methods to store and get data. And Make the ArrayList of that Class instead of the String. Hope you get my point. Feel free for comments.

Comment: the part when you declare String nextuser 3 times really bugs me out. Should i just change subTitleList to 2d array list or there is something i didn't get? Also I cant upvote since i dont have 15 rep ; /

Comment: @Qbee: This is just the Structure code. You can do as you want in it. So is it solve or not ? If not then comment which issue you got ?

Comment: @Qbee: Welcome budy. Comment me for any other help.

Comment: @Qbee, if you have tried this out, how fast it has become now?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely run those in an `AsyncTask`. All you have to do is pass the data into the task's parameters or if you cant figure that out just make your task have a constructor that takes the parameters and call it like this:

```
MyAsync ma = new MyAsync(stuff, stuff, stuff);
ma.execute();
```

In the task's `onPostExecute()` is where you can grab the data from your queries that ran in the background and then you can update the UI.

Also the other guys are kind of right. If you can combine your queries that would be best but with a table like that its not really going to give you much of a performance boost, at least I don't think.

Comment: @ElGavilan: your rejection of the suggested edit is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281860/why-was-my-edit-rejected-and-someone-elses-same-edit-approved).